# Best way to generate slugs when form is filled out in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the devise model called "User" and two other models called client and seller. When a new user signs up, they will have to choose if they are a client or a seller(They can't continue without choosing). Then if they choose "client", they fill out a client form. If they choose "seller", they fill out the seller form. After they submit the form, they will be taken to their seller profile page if they chose seller or they will be taken to the client profile page if they chose client.

That was just some background. Let's take an example client. Let's just say they were the 22nd client to fill out the form. So they become client number 22. So their profile URL looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/client/22
```

I was advised by a few people that it is not good practice to display their id like this to the public and I should generate a "slug" to be shown instead of their client ID. Something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/client/client-name
```

How exactly can I do that? I only need the display on the URL to be changed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gem called [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to achieve this.

Your model would something like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

Check out the [quickstart](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) guide for help.